# WPF TextBox's IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled property is not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus, selection

WPF's TextBox has a property named IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled. I set this property to true in order to make a TextBox always show selection. However, it doesn't work in this case:
[image]

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        textBox.Select(0, 10);
    }
```

I just want to see the selection after clicking the button. But selection will not appear until I right click the TextBox. Why? Am I miss something?

Comment: I had the same problem. Setting the focus in the button click event fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the Keyboard focus on your textbox to select the text in it.

Add this code to your button `click` event before the selection.

```
Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
```

Hope it helps.